# Как занести в переменную рандомное значение в нужном диапазоне?

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Есть переменная `byte x`. В неё нужно внести рандомное значение от 1 до 5 включительно. Моя реализация поставленной задачи выдаёт ошибку. Код:

```
import java.util.Random;       // импортируем Random

Random random = new Random();  // создаём объект класса Random

byte x;                        // переменную x
x = 1+random.nextByte(4)       // ЗДЕСЬ ОШИБКА
```

ошибка: `Error:(№строки) java: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to byte[]`

Comment: какая ошибка все должны догадаться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у `Random` нет метода `nextByte`, но есть `nextBytes`. Однако с помощью него можно складывать сгенерированный байт только в массив.

```
byte[] b = new byte[20];
new Random().nextBytes(b);
```

Можно конечно из `x` сделать массив длиной в 1 и генерировать в него и потом брать по нулевому индексу. Извращение, да.

Но раз задача стоит всего лишь в генерации чисел от 1 до 5, то достаточно будет в данном случае применить `nextInt`, а результат скастовать к `byte`

```
x = (byte) (1 + random.nextInt(5));
```